# Best way to apply code updates to a running website?

Tags: php

How can I apply code changes to my running website, if I have bug fixes or updates?
The simplest way I can think of is to set up the same site in a different directory for testing the changes, and then put my website offline for a period of time to update the files.

Is there a better way?

Comment: If you just need a few hours, I suggest just making it offline during the night time

Comment: If you use decent source control and think things through, it shouldn't take hours to release new code to a website.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Creating a copy of the live site is certainly a good step, applying changes to the copy before applying the same to the live site.

A common production environment would include a further set of steps.

1. **Run a local development copy**
   Have a copy of your website running on your development machine. This requires that you development machine is running a web server, database server and, if necessary, a mail server.
   For PHP/Apache/MySQL environments, take a look at http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html.
   You can safely develop, break, test and change a your local development environment
2. **Source control**
   Use Subversion, Mercurial or Git to keep your code under source control. Ensure your local development environment is kept under source control. Ensure your live environments are under source control. Develop locally, test changes and commit the changes back.
3. **Staging and live environments**
   Maintain more than one 'live' copy - the actual live public site and as close a replica as possible. Ensure both are under version control.
   Once locally-tested changes have been tested, update your staging environment (usin your source control system) and test again. Once your staging site is stable, you can use your source control system to update your live site.
   There will not generally be much of a need to take the real live site offline to apply updates, but be sure that you can safely do so if needed.

Comment: +1 Using source control ensures you can get the new code quickly, minimizing downtime. After that, you just need to hash out the details of testing code before deployment, how to make changes to the production database, etc. And yeah, these are really important, too!

Comment: +1 - very good advice.  You can also consider using a virtual machine as your local development box.  That way, if your server runs, say Debian, you can mirror the exact setup locally, even if you're running windows or whatever on your local machine.

Comment: +1 for using a VM as a duplicate of the production environment.  A good Physical to Virtual tool like VM WAre really helps this process out.

Comment: +1 Create a staging site at some url like testing.mysite.com and when it's ready to go just switch the virtual host the the new directory or move(mv) the files. Or it may be easier to update with version control but be careful not to overwrite config files with things like database passwords.

Answer (score 4):

Jon Cram answered this really well, but I think there's a few more things that are really important when maintaining development environments:

- Evnironments:  Make sure the 2 environments you have are as close as possible to each other. If you're running PHP 5.1, MySQL 5.0, and Apache 2.2 and RHEL in production, make sure you're using exactly the same versions of everything in your sandbox.
- Data: Make a copy of your database, and use that.  DON'T EVAR write or test code against data that's in production.  One `DELETE` without a `WHERE` and you're in trouble. (You have a backup, right?)
- Configuration: Keep all your variables for connecting to databases, email addresses for support, etc in their own file.  This way, you can just swap out connection parameters in your different environments without actually altering code.  Also, I've found it's helpful to commit it separate from your code.
- Build scripts: It's helpful to have a command line script that will handle applying all the changes to your site.  It can as simple as `svn update` or complex enough to require it's own app and library.  See http://phing.info/trac/ for a good example.

Also (shameless plug), here's a post I write a while ago on the importance of sandboxes: http://chr.ishenry.com/2010/02/22/sandboxes/

Comment: Good tip about configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can run new version at different subdomain (or subfolder), and simply change domains handling after testing.

Comment: This could still potentially lead to some data loss if a request is executed right at the moment when you switch.

Comment: Yes can be data lose , but mixing it with putting site offline ,May reduce the downtime very much ! I like the idea

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no better way (duh!)

Well, okay, there might be some better practises, as in you should have a seperate machine for testing purposes. But other than that, don't expect enlightment. You just take the site offline when the load is low (aka during the night) and change/replace stuff.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

Create a Copy of the Live Site on the computer you use for developing the webstie. Follow these steps:
**Setup a Local Testing Server**
Using [Xamp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) you can easily setup a local server on the development computer. Just install all in one server package and copy your website files to htdocs folder. Then you can open your website by just visiting http://localhost/ in the browser. I personally recommend using [Xamp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)
**Source control**
Use Subversion, Mercurial or Git to keep track of updates you make to your site. These softwares keep track of changes you make to every file. They will enable you to undo any error in your website which may occur during development.
**Keeping a Staging live copy of your site** 
Keep a staging live copy of your website on any another location on your server which is exactly same to the publically available live site. Once you update and test the local copy of the site. use your source control software to update the staging live site. When the staging site turn out to be stable and working. Use source control software again to update the publically available live site. This way your website will remain online all the time while you update it.

### Method 2

Its a rather expensive solution ( I personally do not recommended it as the first method will also ensure the same results). If there is no downtime available keep another copy of the site running on other secondary server that you can divert users to when you want to update the main site. After updates you can divert your users back to the actual site. You can also use State server Sitting on another server to ensure that every session is recorded and maintained when user switch form one to another site.

### Method 3 (Easy method for those who do not understand the above two methods)

Install [Xamp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) copy your site files to xamp\htdocs folder. This copied site will be your local copy. Update the site and check it locally by typing and visiting http://localhost/ in your browser. Once the site is checked. Update all the files with filezilla ftp client(select update new files when uploading.).

Answer (score 1):

On very busy sites **AND** severe SLA for downtimes **AND** using apache webserver **AND** for updates involving a significant number of files (eg.: >10), **over the suggestions of "Jon Cram" and "Chris Henry"** you can use this *simple* trick:

in your live environment using 2 document root, 1st with your old files and the 2nd with new files (you have already testing in staging), and symbolic links to share what you cannot duplicate, then:

```
 1. in the apache config file switch the document root from old to new
 2. check the config file (apachectl -S)
 3. graceful restart the apache (apachectl graceful)
```

the apache will finish to serve the old requests in the old environment and start the new requests in the new environment.

- Of course you have already done the patches to DB
- Of course you have to write code that avoid conflicts to DB (eg.: using new tables and
  new cols)
- Of course is more simple: *stop* the site, patch it and restart it

May be you don't use apache but many web server have this capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a copy of your site on your computer. Then after making updates/code changes etc. Update the site with [Filezilla FTP client](http://filezilla-project.org/).
Filezilla will just replace the files that you have updated and during all this process your site will be online.

Comment: yeah I too use Filezilla for this purpose . This way the main site remains online while you update the pages